# Storm ackers are limiting the performance

Tags: apache-storm

I was running a topology with many bolts. From the storm's ui, I can see that the Execute latency and Process latency of all bolts are very small (<1ms). However, the Complete latency of my Spouts raised up to 30s.

I thought such a huge discrepancy is caused by the ackers. Because, the ackers executed 101,522,080 times but only emitted 2,673,260, which means, if I'm correct, there are around 100,000,000 tuples are flying in the topology and waiting for Ack signal.

I tried to set the Ack numbers to 0 and disable Ack at all. But it turned out the entire system is running out of control. Also tried to double the number of ackers, but the situation does not get better.

Is the acker the real problem that limited the performance? And how to optimize such an issue?

Comment: How many ackers do you have? How many different components do you have?

Comment: acker executors -- 20,  executors excluding ackers -- 74, different bolts/spouts -- 29        @poixen

Comment: 29 spouts/bolts? How's your topology look like? As you may noticed, tuple is marked as 'completed' when all tuples in tuple tree are acked, so if you have long and complicated pipeline, complete latency will be going up. What latency is often coming from transferring and waiting in queue between workers.

Comment: And currently 'complete latency' is affected how much ack message from acker is waiting on Spout. This is fixed via STORM-1742, and will be included to Storm 1.1.0 (I'm about to include this to Storm 1.0.3)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1742

Answer (score 0):

First, setting number of ackers to zero means **your spout emits all tuple when they are available** so your topology encounters performance problems, failed tuples and piled up messages in consumer/spout side. Because all of your tuples acked (marked as executed ) instantly **before the tuple executed in all bolts** and **TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING** can't do its real duty.

In my opinion, first try to figure out the best **TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING** count for your topology. Then, tune ackers count.you can double it the number of workers and watch the performance from Strom UI.